# Code First model and deployment of new versions of the software

Tags: deployment, entity-framework-4, code-first, database-first

I'm looking on Entity Framework at the moment and working with Code First example. So far I can see that the framework does not handle model changes easily: whenever I want to add another field to a class/table, framework drops the entire database and creates it from the scratch.

Similar behaviour I saw in (N)Hibernate. (I could be wrong here, it was long time ago)

That is ok, as long as I work on tutorial. When a real-life project is involved, you can't afford to drop a database every time you need a new field in a table.

Just imagine scenario, you are working on a project with many clients. Every client has their own database. In release 1.0.1 I need to add a new field to one of the tables. If I drop database in my dev environment - not a big deal. (Still, I need to run a script to populate test data every time DB is dropped, and sometimes even this is no viable)

But what do I do when I need to deploy this new version? Make a SQL script to update client's databases without dropping them? then deploy binaries?

But how is this better than doing database mods separate from code changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(sorry for my bad english)

This is exactly why Code First Migrations exists. Take a look [here (automatic migrations)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx) and [here (code-based migrations)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, Leo. No need to apologise for English -)